# How to justify text to the top left corner of its container via HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, position, vertical-alignment

I am trying to precisely position some text as an overlay to some content underneath. I have it inside an absolutely positioned box, and that is contained in another box that is relatively positioned. It is something like:

```css
.overlay-container {
  position: relative;
  
  background-color: slategray; width: 260px; height: 100px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  
  font-family: serif; font-size: 54px; color: white;
  font-size: 54px; outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-container">
  <div class="overlay">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

You can see that although the text container is positioned absolutely as `top: 0; left: 0`, the H has plenty of space on top. It is not because the box is not positioned to the top left, as you can see from the outline. It is because the box itself is vertically much larger than necessary, both from its top and its bottom.

My question is, how may I precisely position the top left corner of the H, relative to the top left corner of its container?

This should work regardless of the font size.

Comment: Not font-size, but maybe line-height?

Comment: Use a border instead of the outline or consider the width of the outline when positioning since the outline is always the **out**line.

Comment: @tavkomann I have used outline just to outline the box, really. You can remove the outline if you want, and the problem I am pointing out is still there: The "HELLO" does not touch the top of the orange box.

Comment: Ah, now I understand it. You cannot remove this spacing because it is integrated into the font and not generated by the browser. The only thing you can do is to determine an appropriate value for the `line-height` which is smaller than the `font-size`. Or just use a font which does not have any vertical spacing.